# What are the benefits of using WebAuthn?

Tags: asymmetric, webauthn

The [Web Authentication API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Authentication_API) allows websites served via HTTPS to allow users to authenticate via asymmetric encryption. The procedure for login is basically the following:

1. Server sends a challenge (16 random bytes);
2. Client signs the challenge;
3. Client sends the signature.

How is this better than password-based authentication?

MDN says:

> This resolves significant security problems related to phishing, data breaches, and attacks against SMS texts or other second-factor authentication methods [...]

I don't understand how it prevents phishing or attacks against 2FA methods. Data breach consequences are not reduced if the passwords are properly hashed and TLS already ensures that a man-in-the-middle can't steal the password nor perform replay attacks, right?

Comment: see https://blog.cloudflare.com/cloudflare-now-supports-security-keys-with-web-authentication-webauthn/

Comment: Thanks for the link, @mti2935. It is indeed useful for external authenticators, where you can plug them to any computer and that computer can only login while it has access to the authenticator device.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

WebAuthn essentially protects against phishing.

An attacker can create a fake website (of your bank, for example) and convince you to enter your password on the fake website. Then, the attacker can freely replay it to the real website of the bank.

Same applies for SMS One-Time Passwords (often used as a second factor). For instance, an attacker can impersonate an employee of the bank on the phone and ask you for the SMS code you've just received.

WebAuthn registration bounds the credential to the **domain name** of the legitimate site. An attacker, which doesn't own this domain name, cannot in any circumstance get a valid WebAuthn authentication response (and replay it on the legitimate site) from a fake website because of that.

Answer (score 0):

> Data breach consequences are not reduced if the passwords are properly hashed

I wanted to add, in addition the @Tangui's answer, than proper hashing doesn't necessarily prevent password theft. Password hashing primarily (not only, but primarily) protects against attackers who would compromise the server, but an attacker who managed to compromise the server could also eavesdrop on the passwords as the traffic that contains them are decrypted by the server-side TLS. Such an attacker would only be able to read in-flight passwords rather than the entire password database, but that is certainly still useful enough.

WebAuthn prevents this, since the server only keeps the public key of the credential, which is not security-sensitive to begin with.

Further, from the user's point of view, it also means that you don't need to trust a particular web service to do proper password hashing, as you're not giving the server any sensitive data to begin with.